# Run database query with laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I wonder is there any difference by performance between running query in laravel blade and running query in controller. And how correct is running query in view?

Comment: Well, You shouldn't run any query in view becasue it's a mixing the presentation layer with application logic layer which is not good at all. However, when You're using relations and You will call them somewhere inside the view (often example with: `@foreach($model->relations as $relation)`) it will create query first.
Best place for quering is inside controller or sometime through the view composer.

Comment: no i mean without relation for example `@foreach(App\Model::latest()->get() as $item)` is there any difference with performace